# How to create a YTD using fiscal year / financial year

Tags: powerbi, time-series, dax, yearmonth, fiscal

Apologises if this question has already been raised but I'm struggling with my data model to create a rolling total / YTD sales using fiscal years.

I know PowerBI/DAX is great using calendar Jan-Dec dates but how do you amend this if your financial year begins in March-April instead?

When I created my calendar table, I used the CALENDEARAUTO() which gave me a column of dates from Jan to Dec as expected and when I change the function to CALENDERAUTO(3), my date column begins from March to April which makes sense.

However, if I use the CALCULATE and DATESYTD functions to sum the total sales column and choose the date column as described above, the result looks like:

## Actual YTD = CALCULATE(sum('spend'[Actual]),DATESYTD('Fiscal Year Table'[Date],"03-31"))

[image]

What do I need to do exactly for it work in this exact date format?

[image]

Many thanks

Hash